# Why wasn't Linda Hamilton in T3?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-3-rise-of-the-machines

What is the reason that Linda Hamilton didn't reprise the character of Sarah Connor in *Terminator 3: Rise of the Machines*?

Was she busy on another film or had she stated no interest in appearing in the third film?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Linda Hamilton claimed it was because she felt that her character arc was complete and that the new script didn't offer her much.

> **Q:** ***Your character went through an amazing arc in the sequel...***
>
> **LH:** *How lucky am I? I loved it. I turned down "T3" because I really did feel that it was so complete, that the character arc was completely there and could not be improved upon. And the script that I read proved that to me! But I'm retiring a champ.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Linda Hamilton - Terminator 2: Judgment Day DVD](http://www.bbc.co.uk/films/2001/10/30/linda_hamilton_2001_interview.shtml)</sup></sub>

and

> *"They offered me a part. I read it and I knew my character arc was so
> complete in the first two, and in the third one it was a negligible
> character,"* she explained. *"She died halfway through and there was no
> time to mourn her. It was kind of disposable, so I said no thank you."*
>
> <sub><sup>[Linda Hamilton confirms 'T4' talks](https://www.digitalspy.com/movies/a147341/linda-hamilton-confirms-t4-talks/)</sup></sub>

Apparently she was also undergoing treatment at this point for her (pre-existing) [bipolar disorder](http://transcripts.cnn.com/TRANSCRIPTS/0510/14/lkl.01.html) and it was only a couple of years after a messy divorce so it's certainly possible that she had some personal issues that prevented her from accepting the role. To deal with her absence, the writers [dropped a bridge on her](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DroppedABridgeOnHim) by giving her fatal leukaemia.

Comment: Why is she returning now, then?

Comment: @HamSandwich - I would imagine it's because a) Her career is in the toilet and b) Money and C) Flattery