# What do we know about the (earlier) Terminator 3 script?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-3-rise-of-the-machines

According to this [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/218329/why-wasnt-linda-hamilton-in-t3), Linda Hamilton turned down a part in the third film was because she wasn't happy with the script. Are there any known details of this script? Given the presence of the part strong parts: John Connor and Kate Brewster, what room was there for Sarah Connor? Or was the role of Kate Brewster made more prominent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it's not entirely clear which draft version of the script Linda Hamilton was referring to, we do have access to the first draft of T3: Rise of the Machines by Tedi Sarafian, in which Sarah dies.

You can read a copy online [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140912071821/http://www.cinefile.biz/script/terminator3.pdf). Kate Brewster doesn't exist. The (Arnie) Terminator is originally assumed to be the baddie and the T-1G (advanced prototype Terminatrix) seems to be protecting John

> until it becomes clear that she's just using him to get to Skynet in order to help it evolve.

Oh, and Sarah dies on page 109 of 119, not "*halfway*" in but I can imagine that Linda Hamilton was pretty grumpy about not making it to the end, especially when she's barely in the first 48 pages.